# Configuring Openfire using Ansible

Tags: ansible, openfire

I have installed and downloaded `Openfire` using `Ansible scripts`, but I was wondering if there is a way I can configure `Openfire` through `Ansible`.

The documentation only mentions web-based console as a way to configure it. Configuration involves adding database connection details, port number, including security certificates & other configuration details.

[Link to documentation](http://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html#tools)

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention it but presumably what ever you set in the UI gets written to some form of config file(s). You need to find this config and then template it or use `lineinfile` to modify the configuration and then presumably reload the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openfire (4.0.2) it's full configurable by:

- XML (openfiredir/conf/openfire.xml and security.xml),
- database insert/entry (mainly "ofProp" table),
- deploying jar in /lib directory
- deploying plugins copying jar in /plugins directory and then unzip those
  jar in same directory under a selfish-named directory.

As I know there's no doc about what to do: just do once with web admin console and then export the database + xml files

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! This is quite helpful.